# How to create custom integer sequence in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I have function like this:

```
template <typename ... Types>
void foo(const Types & ... values)
{
    // expected that 'values' is sequence like
    // '1, customvalue1, 2, customvalue2, 3,...'
}
```

And second function:

```
template <typename ... Types>
void bar(const Types & ... values)
{
    // where 'values' are any variables
    // some magic here
    foo((int_seq<sizeof...(Types)>, values)...);
}
```

I'd like to pass any sequence of variables to **bar**, so that this sequence convert to sequence like **'1, value1, 2, value2, 3, value3'**. So each value follows its number in base sequence. But I cannot create this **'magic code'** to transform sequence on compile phase between this two state.

Comment: I assume that `bar` is supposed to call `foo`? Not call itself recursively?

Comment: have you looked at an associative array? This seems like a problem for this type of data structure

Comment: Yes, i was wrong, it's of course 'foo', not 'bar'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really elegant but, using tuples, `std::tie`, etc...

The following example should work with C++11

**--- EDIT ---**

Modified and unified (C++11 without C++14 elements) my first example.

There is no need of `std::index_sequence` (a trivial `struct indSeq` can be used instead) or `std::make_index_sequence` (the index sequence can be contructed step by step using `sizeof...(I)`); no need of `qux()` anymore.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>


void foo ()
 { }

template <typename T0, typename ... Types>
void foo (const T0 & v0, const Types & ... values)
 {
   std::cout << "-- " << v0 << std::endl;

   foo(values...);
 }


template <std::size_t ...>
struct indSeq
 { };

template <std::size_t ... Is, typename ... Ts1>
void baz (std::size_t, const indSeq<Is...> &, const std::tuple<Ts1...> & t)
 { foo(std::get<Is>(t)...); }

template <std::size_t ... Is, typename ... Ts1, typename T0, typename ... Ts2>
void baz (std::size_t n, const indSeq<Is...> &, const std::tuple<Ts1...> & t,
          const T0 & v0, const Ts2 & ... vs)
 { baz(n+1U, indSeq<Is..., sizeof...(Is), sizeof...(Is)+1U>(),
       std::tuple_cat(t, std::tie(n), std::tie(v0)), vs...); }

template <typename ... Types>
void bar (const Types & ... values)
 { baz (1U, indSeq<>(), std::tuple<>(), values...); }

int main()
 {
   bar(11, 22L, "33", 44.44);
   return 0;
 }
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a C++14 solution, but all the necessary library parts can be written in C++11 as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename ... Types>
void foo(const Types & ... values)
{
    using swallow = bool[];
    (void)swallow{ (std::cout << values << std::endl,false)... };
}

template <std::size_t N, bool = (N%2==0)>
struct pick {
    template<typename... Types>
    static std::size_t get(const std::tuple<Types...>&) { return N/2; }
};

template <std::size_t N>
struct pick<N,false> {
    template<typename... Types>
    static auto get(const std::tuple<Types...>& t) { return std::get<N/2>(t); }
};

template <std::size_t... Indices, typename ... Types>
void bar2(const std::index_sequence<Indices...>, const Types & ... values)
{
    auto x = std::tie(values...);
    foo(pick<Indices>::get(x)...);
}

template <typename ... Types>
void bar(const Types & ... values)
{
    bar2(std::index_sequence_for<Types...,Types...>(), values...);
}

int main()
{
    bar( "Hallo", 42, 1.23 );
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aab30fcad790aa40)

It is currently zero-based, but a `+1` in the right place will fix that easily. Also, it creates an intermediate `std::tuple` with references to the values, if performance is an issue better options might exist but since you weren't using `std::forward` I figured that a small performance impact might be acceptable for you.

Comment: I would have found making a tuple-of-2-tuples, then flattening, to be my default approach.  In C++17, I could use `if constexpr`, `tupler`, a lambda and `std::apply` to do the call inline, which would be really fun.